# calling a function within a function not working, uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, typeerror

This might sound similar to other questions, but just hear me out. I have a function called `bullet(x, y, w, h)` and a function inside that called `this.trigger()` i want to call the `this.trigger()` in a keyDown function.

This is the bullet function

```js
 function bullet(x, y, w, h) {

  //x value of bullet is the x value of the player + 27
  this.x = player.x + 27;

  //y value of bullet is the y value of the player
  this.y = player.y;

  //the width of the bullet
  this.w = w;

  //the height of the bullet
  this.h = h;

  //boolean for whether fired is true or false
  this.fired = false;

  //This function draws the player
  this.draw = function() {

   // states what x of the bullet is
   this.x = player.x + 28;

   //sets fillStyle to "red"
   context.fillStyle = "red";

   //Fills the rectangle red
   context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,5,10);

  };


  //function which moves the bullet
  this.trigger = function() {

   //If this.fired = true; if statement runs
   if(this.fired) {
    //makes the bullet's y value go down by 10
    this.y -= 10;
   }

   //If the bullet's y value is lower than 0; if statement runs
   if (this.y < 0) {

    //this.fired is now false
    this.fired = false;

    //sets the bullet y value to player y value
    this.y = player.y;

   }

  };

 }
```

This is the keydown function:

```js
 // controls to shoot the bullet when the user presses the key
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  //if the player presses the spacebar run the statement
  if(event.keyCode == 32) {

   //bullet.fired is now equal to true
   bullet.fired = true;

   //calls bullet.trigger
   bullet.trigger();


 }

 });
```

In this code it comes up with the error: Uncaught TypeError: bullet.trigger is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.

This is also my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so any feedback is appreciated. :)

Comment: You cannot call `bulet.trigger()` as `bullet` itself is a function.

Comment: @front_end_dev so how exactly would I call the bullet.trigger() function?

Comment: Functions are 1st class objects in javascript so this can be done if he were to call `new bullet(...).trigger();`  However I think we may need more context:  Are you creating an instance of `bullet`? Where is `player` defined? etc

Comment: hold the reference of the outer function `var b = new bullet(x,y,w,h)`. then inside the keydown listener replace `bullet.trigger();`  to `b.trigger();`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a class instead of a function?

Comment: @front_end_dev so I create a new function called something and create a new variable called var b = new bullet(x,y,w,h) ? or just have a line of code outside the function called var b = new bullet(x,y,w,h)?

Comment: If the variables pass into the `bullet` function is change with `keydown` event then create a new object inside the keydown listener function if not the do it above the keydown addEventListener line.